# What is the 5000th happy prime number?

Tags: sequences-and-series, prime-numbers

Im writing a program that finds the Nth [happy prime number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Happy_number). I think it works, but to double check I want to compare what it returns for the 5000th happy prime number. The problem is, I dont know where to get a verified result. I tried to look on [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Happy_number#Happy_primes) and [OEIS](http://oeis.org/A035497), but neither list a large amount of happy primes. So how else can I verify my result?

Edit: I believe that the 5000th (or maybe its the 4999th) happy prime number is 400087

Comment: Is the Wiki link I edited in correct?

Comment: No matter which number it is, it is happy...:-)

Comment: Isn't it right here? http://oeis.org/A035497/b035497.txt

Comment: @IanColey yeah, I was looking at this: http://oeis.org/A035497/list

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you're looking for a large list on OEIS, you should be looking in the Links and References sections, not the blurb at the top. In this case the very first link is [a table of the first 10000 happy primes](http://oeis.org/A035497/b035497.txt). Your value is indeed the 4999th.

The 5000th happy prime is `400157`.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks. And my program works :)

Comment: +1 where is this link exactly? Got it...

Answer (score 1):

You are correct. The first prime is 2 so all even numbers can't be prime. Then the next one is 3. 5 is prime and all multiples of 5 end in 0 or 5. Each number can only be prime once . 7 is the next prime number. All multiples of 7 are not prime. Step 2, draw a circle so that you put the even number , N= 10 at the zero point, and N/2 (5) at the bottom . N-1 = 9, . 9 is not prime, so we move on. The next even number is 12; In the circle ,the 0 point at the top begins and ends at the same place. We are checking to see if 11 is prime,  it is not, . All odd numbers , prime or not,  are of the form (N-1). If you continue, you will notice that the next even # is 14. The #14 is the #of radii in the circle. To maintain the integrity of the circle, all the angles in between the radii are equal to each other. The #1 + the #(N-1) = N. The end point of each radii is important. looking again at the #12 circle, 1 +11=12; 2+10= 12; 3 + 9= 12; and so on . Mark each prime number. Keep making circles, the next one being #14. Follow thru with each multiple of the prime #'s, 2,3,5, so you will find the next prime,  14-1=13. Julie Yancey.